# Whats the fastest way to remove all occurrences of a value from an array is splicing it the fastest or is filter faster?

Tags: javascript

so like:

```
array.filter(i => i !== item)
```

would this would be faster than something like

```
var i = array.length;

    while (i--) {
        if (array[i] === item) {
            array.splice(array.indexOf(item), 1);
        }
    }
```

when looking at performance. I want to remove multiple instances of the same thing in an array

Comment: Why not [make a performance test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Timers) yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algorithmically, `filter` should win; it performs a single read and write pass building a single new `Array` in order, `O(n)`. `splice` would have to do the same amount of reading no matter what, and write work would match just to splice out a single matching value at the beginning of the array, almost twice as much if it occupies the first two elements of the array, etc. It may not be quite `O(n²)` in practice given that more instances of the element reduce work for subsequent splices, but it's close (you'd see effectively `O(n²)` behavior for an array of `n` matching elements followed by `n` non-matching elements that have to be copied down `n` times by the `n` splices).

As for which is faster in practice, you'd have to test, but for large arrays, I'd definitely favor `filter` by default. `splice` should only win in the rare cases where memory is at a premium, and avoiding copying might make a difference (extremely unusual).

Comment: Regarding memory I guess that would even apply only for primitive values (which OP is probably using), objects would just have their references copied, not much memory impact compared to a new Array.

Comment: @Kaiido: Even references add up; it may not be a big increase as a percentage, but 10 million references (pointers) is still 80 MB of memory on a 64 bit system, which could be the straw that broke the camel's back (causing swap/pagefile activity at a fraction of RAM speeds)..